# store, remove and re apply class attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to temporary get rid of class attributes on html element to do sone parsing on it, however I need to store removed attribute somewhere and then somehow re-apply it back.

So far, I know I can pop and add attributes like this

```
div.removeAttribute("class")
div.setAttribute("class", "myClassname")
```

but that doesn't really help me out in terms of storing and re-applying it.

Comment: Can you set them to another attribute?

Comment: @dfsq noup, reason for doing this is so I can parse clean html element like `h1` with no attributes on it for example (class is just one example here to make question neater)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store class attribute in some helper property which is not exposed as attribute. You can do it because HTMLElement's are normal objects so you can manipulate/set/read their properties, also create custom:

```javascript
// set helper property
div.oldClass = div.className

// remove class attribute
div.removeAttribute('class')

// restore class attribute
div.setAttribute("class", div.oldClass)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not like

```
div.removeAttribute("class")
div.setAttribute("class", "myClassname")
```

It is like

```
div.removeAttr("class")
div.Attr("class", "myClassname")
```

I may be wrong either.. Jus give a try

Comment: Really? I think you are confusing pure DOM API with jQuery, and even in jQuery it should be `attr` lowercase. Plus you didn't understand the question OP is asking. Hes code works (the first part of your answer), but it's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  attr = $("div").attr("class");
  $("div").removeAttr("class");
  $("div").attr("class", attr);
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/bugyt/pen/grLGJb)